# Pop appending but not removing from original list

Tags: python, stack

What would cause a .pop(-1) command to do the append but leave a copy of the item behind? After the pop command there are two copies of the item in the list, one in the append location and one in the pop from location.

```
for i in range(8):
    if Tabloid_face_up[i] != [] and Tabloid_face_up[i][-1][0] == "A":
        for j in range(8,12):
             if Tabloid_face_up[j] == []:
                 Tabloid_face_up[j].append(Tabloid_face_up[i].pop(-1))
                 if Tabloid_face_down[i] != []:
                     Tabloid_face_up[i].append(Tabloid_face_down[i][-1])
                 break
```

It's supposed to move the card from i to j but I end up with it at both i and j.

Comment: uh, Sorry. What happened to my tabbing?

Comment: You needed 4 spaces at the beginning of the first line, which I added for you.

Comment: Consider the pop line when both i and j are 8.

Comment: @gaige I don't think `i` can be `8`. `range(8)` -> `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, no?

Comment: Can you post a minimal and complete example showing your problem?

Comment: True enough.  They will not be both 8. Sorry about that.

Comment: Most likely you're adding another item to the list by the line `Tabloid_face_up[i].append(Tabloid_face_down[i][-1])`. Impossible to tell with the incomplete code though.

Comment: Put a `print()` before and after the `pop()` - I will guarantee it is removing it, you must be adding it back somewhere.

Comment: 1. I'm using first 7 (0 through 6)for foundation, 8th (#7) is the waste and range(8,12) is the foundation (8,9,10,11).

Comment: Here is a result showing the AH in THREE places. I don't know what else in my code would be applicable and it won't let me give all of it.


0  =  ['7H', '6C']
1  =  ['QS']
2  =  ['8D']
3  =  ['2H']
4  =  ['AH']
5  =  ['2S']
6  =  ['5S']
7  =  []
8  =  ['AC']
9  =  ['AH']
10  =  []
11  =  []
Move card from: 4
Move to: F
0  =  ['7H', '6C']
1  =  ['QS']
2  =  ['8D']
3  =  ['2H']
4  =  ['AH']
5  =  ['2S']
6  =  ['5S']
7  =  []
8  =  ['AC']
9  =  ['AH']
10  =  ['AH']
11  =  []
PS is there a line return other than 'return' (which posts the comment?)

Comment: Tabloid_face_up[i].append(Tabloid_face_down[i][-1] is wrong. Corrected to Tabloid_face_up[i].append(Tabloid_face_down[i].pop(-1)). But I don't see how that would affect the other line - since it was supposed to be replacing the moved card - but wasn't.